# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). how to solve it?

Tags: java, netbeans

i cant insert my data from java to database

This is the sql and statement

```
//query
String username = txtUsername.getText();
String password = txtPassword.getText();
String namabisnis = txtBisnis.getText();

String sql = "insert into user (username,password,namabisnis)  values('?','?','?')";

try {
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, namabisnis);

    int masuk = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);

    lblerror.setTextFill(Color.TOMATO);
    lblerror.setText("Akun Anda Sudah Didaftarkan, Silahkan Login");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    //return "Exception";
    lblerror.setTextFill(Color.TOMATO);
    lblerror.setText("Error Saat Mendaftarkan Akun");
}
```

I get the following error:

> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Remove single quotes from your query (`'?'` ⇒ `?`):

```
String sql = "insert into user (username,password,namabisnis)  values(?,?,?)";
```

---

> I get following error again: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1*

That's because you need to call `executeUpdate()` without parameters. Passing in the query will make it execute without bindings (quotation marks won't be replaced).

Call it without parameters instead:

```
int masuk = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: i get following error again

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1